# About Observer interface in Observer Pattern of GoF?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm reading about Observer Pattern of GoF, the UML in the book: [image: UML of Observer Pattern]

From the above diagram, how many ***Observer*** interface are there in a system if I have two different **ConcreteSubject** classes? Would they share the same ***Observer*** interface? Or is that each **(Concrete)Subject** classes should have its corresponding ***Observer*** interface for which those **ConcreteObserver** classes interested in it can subscribe?

If entire system share only one ***Observer*** interface, as the diagram expressed, then how can a class subscribe(i.e. **implement**) for many different **ConcreteSubject** classes? Wouldn't all the code for different **ConcreteSubject** classes lumped into the same **ConcreteObserver** class?

Could anyone point out which part(s) is(are) incorrect?

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding - a design pattern is just a concept;  it's not a set of rules which dictate how to implement your code.    If you are trying to implement the pattern exactly as described in the GoF book then you're missing the point.    You should implement your code in whatever way actually meets your requirements, Therefore, if you need multiple Subjects or multiple Observers then that is a matter for your specific implementation; there's no right or wrong way to use the pattern as long as you aren't attempting to fit a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: @BenCottrell: I'm trying to verify my concept about it through the diagram it provided. My current understanding from this pattern is that the subject shouldn't assume much about its observers' actual types and this is done by an abstract interface Observer, and my question is that whether each subject has its own Observer interface.

Comment: What you're asking here is really an implementation detail which depends upon your requirements.   If you have a requirement which means that each of your subjects *need* to expose a different interface for each subject (because you are observing different things) then there's nothing wrong with that.    Similarly, if you don't need multiple different interfaces then you gain no benefit by creating additional redundant interfaces.

Comment: @BenCottrell: Thank you, I thought only one would be correct...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm trying to verify my concept about it through the diagram it provided. My current understanding from this pattern is that the subject shouldn't assume much about its observers' actual types and this is done by an abstract interface Observer, and my question is that whether each subject has its own Observer interface.
>
> [Comment by Niing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/389559/about-observer-interface-in-observer-pattern-of-gof#comment857392_389567)

The abstract `Subject` and the abstract `Observer` have no knowledge of the concrete details. They only know enough to let the `Subject` control when updates happen. Not how.

`ConcreteObserver`s may be many different types but they all must know enough about the `ConcreteSubject` to request and use `subjectState`.  `ConcreteSubject`s can be different types as well provided requesting and using their `subjectState` is identical. A different interface could be created to ensure this if needed but that's not usually part of whats called the observer pattern.

> I think I still can't understand about how one observer subscribe for multiple subjects, but I appreciate your current answer
>
> [Comment by Niing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/389559/about-observer-interface-in-observer-pattern-of-gof/389569#comment857401_389569)

One `observer` subscribing to multiple `subjects` isn't the usual pattern but it's possible, in two different ways:

First we should be clear if we're talking about classes or objects. What you've been looking at above is a class diagram. One class can be used to create multiple objects configured in different ways. That can cause confusion with this question so let me address both.

In the case where there are many different classes talking to many other and different classes all of the above still works provided you allow for polymorphism in some way. Whatever defines the `getState()` method signature, and so the `subjectState` returned, needs to hide the differences in the different `ConcreteSubject`s from the `ConcreteObserver`.

In other words `ConcreteObserver` doesn't need to know what it's talking to. Just how to talk to it. So long as it doesn't know what exactly it's talking to, it can talk to anything that speaks it's language. Polymorphism in a nutshell.

In the case where they are simply different objects but always of the same types (classes or interfaces) the polymorphism requirement can be lessened since the only difference between the objects is their state and reference address.

However, if your issue is actually that you want one `observer` object to be able to track multiple `subject` objects at the same time there is a minor tweak that helps. In this situation it's easy to get confused and ask for `getState()` from the wrong `subject`. A nifty trick is to have your `subject` send a `this` or `self` (depending on language) reference back with the `update()`. This way you know exactly which `subject` to call `getState()` on.

When there's only one `subject` this is sometimes left out of the pattern because they can reuse the reference that was used to subscribe. Why not do it every time? [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

And as [Caleth points out](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/389559/about-observer-interface-in-observer-pattern-of-gof/389569#comment857402_389569) you don't have to use a getter at all. You can have the `subject` send `subjectState` as a parameter of `Update`.

On the issue of using getter vs parameter you wont find many observer pattern text authors commenting. You will find plenty of [tell, don't ask](https://www.google.com/search?q=tell%2C+don%27t+ask&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1) authors commenting.

If you want to go down that road I highly advise you be sure you [know the difference between an event and a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962755/why-are-commands-and-events-separately-represented) because you're creating an event and should treat it as such.

Comment: I think I still can't understand about how one observer subscribe for multiple subjects, but I appreciate your current answer...

Comment: @Niing In the above diagram, it doesn't. If you leave off the `subject` member, and instead pass the state as a parameter to `Notify`, then you can easily have an `Observer` watching multiple `Subject`s

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your "In the case where there are many different *class*es with different *type*s...", I used the word __type__ in your first quoted description but I actually regarded it the same as __class__, could you elaborate more about "classes with different types"? (And many thanks for helpful edit!)

Comment: @Niing better now?

Comment: "In other words ConcreteObserver doesn't need to know what it's talking to. Just how to talk to it.": so ConcreteObserver should use `Subject` interface to talk to those different `ConcreteSubject`s, but `Subject` interface don't define `getState()`? (Sorry if this is too implementation details but I would like to implement it after all...)

Comment: @Niing Correct. `Subject` doesn't define `getState()`. At least not according to your diagram. `getStates()` signature is defined by `ConcreteSubject`. If there is no way to polymorphically deploy that method you're stuck with this one implementation. A keyword Interface, abstract class, or a delegating class composed of another class could all give you the polymorphic power to change the getters implementation. It doesn't have to be the `Subject` interface that `ConcreteObserver` uses for this. It could be. But that will couple the Observer system to `subjectState`. Not very reusable.

Comment: Many thanks for all your explanations, and kindness, I think I this book is just too complicated for me, at least for this specific pattern....

Comment: @Niing oh the GoF book was ground breaking but it's nearly unreadable. Try reading it along side something like Head First Design Patterns. It isn't often the first to publish an idea is also the best one to explain it.

Comment: @Niing One other tweak that is often used with this pattern along with passing a reference to the changed object is to pass the name of the property that was changed and the old and new values for that property.  This is useful for building detailed audit logs and ledgers.

Answer (score 0):

The *Observer* interface should be 1 and so should be the *Subject*. This is done for decoupling. The actual concrete observer(s) and subject(s) will implement these interfaces.

In your *ConcreteSubject* you ll maintain a list of *Observer* and you can have there different classes of *ConcreteObserver*. So, the relationship of *ConcreteObserver* and *ConcreteSubject* is not 1-1 (or else we wouldn't need the interfaces).

Comment: Suppose a __Person__ interested in __BookStore__'s weekly news, and __Library__'s weekly news, so the person will subscribe for both subjects, then if only one interface __BookReader__, a __Person__ class will contain two unrelated implementation in it, wouldn't this cause any problem?

Comment: you will have 1 class implemenring observer, *Person* and 2 implementing observables, *BooStore* and *Library*, if i get it right. The person will be injected in constructor a list of observables. This way person subscribes where u want and stays decoupled. Am i missing something on your question?

Comment: Since only 1 class __Person__ implements the observer interface(__BookReader__), it will have only one `update()` method from this interface, but this person subscribes to two observables, which means this single `update()` method have to contain two segments of code dealing with two different observables. So wouldn't this be a problem?

Comment: i think this pattern focuses on how, many observers can subscribe to one observable. if 1 observable notifies observers calling `update(x, y)` then an observer can use abstracrion in its 'update' and the other division. Not on how one observer can subscribe with the same method in 2 observables. then u might need 2 implementations of the pattern, with 2 'update' methods etc. But u can even subscribe to 2 subjects, if they are handled similarly, if you pass the proper params in 'update'. So if the latter is the case, u have the pattern and the concepts behind it. Try to use it for your own case